# SSL failing with Allow Arbitrary Loads = false

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ssl

As per my requirement i should not make **Allow Arbitrary Loads = true**. So i set to false.

And i am allowing the trust certificate on my URLsession delegate.

**My url** : https://sample-app.10.names.io

**code :**

```
public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
       //Trust the certificate even if not valid
       let urlCredential = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
       completionHandler(.useCredential, urlCredential)
    }
```

**My error :**

**Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?,**

If I make **Allow Arbitrary Loads = true**, then only its working. But as per my requirement i should not change to true. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks

Update:

I tried this below too :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>https://sample-app.10.names.io</key>
        <dict>
            <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the terminal command

`nscurl --ats-diagnostics --verbose https://sample-app.10.names.io`

to test your server for ATS compliance.

Doing so reveals that your server only passes when [perfect forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy) is disabled.  It would seem that your server does not support ECDHE ciphers.

You can configure ATS to ignore the perfect forward secrecy requirement by specifying [NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsexceptionrequiresforwardsecrecy) in your ATS configuration exception domains, but really you should patch your server to use newer TLS code.  Otherwise it is vulnerable to replay MITM attacks.

Answer (score -1):

If you are actively using `Alamofire` in your project, I suggest you use the built-in `Session` that can be configured to use your server trust certificate without much hassle. Here is some code on how it is setup in one of my projects.

```
class SessionManagerProvider {

// MARK: - State

let hosts: [String]
let disableEvaluation: Bool

// MARK: - Init

init(urls: [URL], disableEvaluation: Bool = false) {
    hosts = urls.compactMap { $0.host }
    self.disableEvaluation = disableEvaluation
}

// MARK: - Factory

func make() -> Session {
    // Configure network client with SSL pinning.
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = Constants.Backend.timeoutIntervalForRequest
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = Constants.Backend.timeoutIntervalForResource
    // Allow more connections than API requests to avoid an issue, when URLSession starts to
    // time-out requests when there are too many connections.
    configuration.httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost = Constants.maxConcurrentApiCalls * 2
    let policies = serverTrustPolicies(disableEvaluation: disableEvaluation)
    let securityManager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: policies)
    let sessionManager = Session(configuration: configuration, serverTrustManager: securityManager)
    return sessionManager
}

private func serverTrustPolicies(disableEvaluation: Bool) -> [String: ServerTrustEvaluating] {
    var policies: [String: ServerTrustEvaluating] = [:]

    for host in hosts {
        if disableEvaluation {
            policies[host] = DisabledTrustEvaluator()
        } else {
            policies[host] = PublicKeysTrustEvaluator(
                performDefaultValidation: true,
                validateHost: true
            )
        }
    }

    return policies
}
```

}

Comment: I compared the certificate with server and then i am passing as trusted certificate. But if i changes my `Allow Arbitrary Loads = true` then it working. But as per my requirement it has to be `FALSE`.

Comment: I get what your saying. TRUE  means that you allow insecure HTTP (without the S) connections to your app, which makes it unsafe.

Comment: Yes, but i am allowing the certificate as trusted one. But still no success.